# Display/Map Nested JSON fields in React JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, material-ui

This is my first time to post here in SO. I'm currently developing my skills at JavaScript, React and Material-UI. I am trying to display in a table the biller data from my sample nested JSON file.

**It logs in the console but I can't understand why it doesn't display in my table. Please help me :(**

Here is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "transactions": [
        {
          "referenceNumber": "2323",
          "transaction": "Reload",
          "details": {
            "sourceAccntNickname": "6jkp",
            "sourceAcountNicknae": "6*****48",
            "transactionDate": "Feb 08, 2018",
            "biller": [
              {
                "billerName": "AT&T",
                "billerAccntNumber": "6***98"
              }
            ],
            "recurring": false,
            "amount": 600000
          },
          "status": "failed"
        },
        {
          "referenceNumber": "2323",
          "transaction": "Reload",
          "details": {
            "sourceAccntNickname": "7jkp",
            "sourceAcountNicknae": "7*****48",
            "transactionDate": "Feb 09, 2018",
            "biller": [
              {
                "billerName": "AT&T",
                "billerAccntNumber": "6***98"
              }
            ],
            "recurring": true,
            "frequency": "Monthly",
            "amount": 700000
          },
          "status": "failed"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here is my code for displaying the data to my table:

```
<TableBody>
          {stableSort(SchedData, getComparator(order, orderBy)).map(
            (data, index) => {
              return (
                <TableRow tabIndex={-1} key={index}>
                  <TableCell>
                    {data.data.transactions.map((date, index) => {
                      return (
                        <Typography key={index}>
                          {date.details.transactionDate}
                        </Typography>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    {data.data.transactions.map((rec, index) => {
                      return (
                        <h1 key={index}>
                          {rec.details.recurring === false ? (
                            <Typography>Future-dated</Typography>
                          ) : (
                            <Typography>{rec.details.frequency}</Typography>
                          )}
                        </h1>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align='right'>
                    {data.data.transactions.map((bil, index) => {
                      bil.details.biller.map((bilNameAcct, index) => {
                        console.log(
                          bilNameAcct.billerName,
                          bilNameAcct.billerAccntNumber
                        );
                        return (
                          <Typography key={index}>
                            {bilNameAcct.billerName}
                            <br />
                            {bilNameAcct.billerAccntNumber}
                          </Typography>
                        );
                      });
                    })}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align='right'></TableCell>
                  <TableCell align='right'></TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            }
          )}
        </TableBody>
```

Here is a image copy of my output and console:
[OUTPUT/CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQvBe.png)

Any help and tips will be SO much appreciated. Thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return result from `map()` function.

Your code:

```
data.data.transactions.map((bil, index) => {
  bil.details.biller.map((bilNameAcct, index) => { 
    /* ... */ 
  })
})
```

Working code:

```
data.data.transactions.map((bil, index) => {
  return bil.details.biller.map((bilNameAcct, index) => { 
    /* ... */ 
  })
})
```

Full `<TableCell />`:

```
<TableCell align="right">
  {data.data.transactions.map((bil, index) => {
    return bil.details.biller.map((bilNameAcct, index) => {
      console.log(
        bilNameAcct.billerName,
        bilNameAcct.billerAccntNumber
      );
      return (
        <Typography key={index}>
          {bilNameAcct.billerName}
          <br />
          {bilNameAcct.billerAccntNumber}
        </Typography>
      );
    });
  })}
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed return in map function

```
 <TableCell align='right'>
    {data.data.transactions.map((bil, index) => {
      return bil.details.biller.map((bilNameAcct, index) => { // you missed it here
        console.log(
          bilNameAcct.billerName,
          bilNameAcct.billerAccntNumber
        );
        return (
          <Typography key={index}>
            {bilNameAcct.billerName}
            <br />
            {bilNameAcct.billerAccntNumber}
          </Typography>
        );
      });
    })}
  </TableCell>
```